# Copy and paste active column without changing cells formats

Tags: vba, excel

This code helps me to copy and paste active column in values but the numbers are pasted with two decimals. I'm using this code because my sheet has merged cells inside and also some cells within the column have dates.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).EntireColumn.Value = ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Value
```

I need to paste the column in values exactly in the format that the column has the format. Leave the numbers without the decimals.

Note: If you do it manually by selecting the column and then selecting paste in values from  the Home bar, it pastes it exactly as it was with the formulas.

Comment: This code has nothing to do with copy and paste. It assigns values.

Comment: Do you know then how to copy active column with merged cells and paste it in values?

Comment: @pnuts Yes but I added a comment and seems nobody responded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
Dim r As Long
c = Selection.Column

Range(Cells(4, c + 1), Cells(5, c + 1)).Merge
Columns(c).EntireColumn.Copy
Columns(c + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

You may need to tweak some stuff, like merging certain cells, where you want the cell pasted in relation to the copied cell. Let me know how this works

Comment: It copies the active column 4 times next to this one and deletes all merged cells. Do you know a way to copy the active column and paste in values even if it has merged cells?

Comment: Could you try explaining that in a different way? The way this one is set up is it copies the active column (c) and pastes it to the column next to it (c + 1). In the example I used, I assumed that the active column had the cells in rows 4 and 5 merged, so I first merged the cells to the right of the active column before pasting them over. So whatever cells you have that are merged in your active column should first be merged in the column that you are going to paste in. You can use the merge function (in the example above, Range(Cells(x, c + 1), Cells(5, c + 1)).Merge) as many times as needed